# Resizing dynamic TableLayout in android

Tags: android, dynamic, resize, android-tablelayout

I have created a dynamic TableLayout in Android. The problem is, there is an unnecessary gap in the column. I'd like to remove it, I've been changing the code a few times but the results are astonishing. Here is the best that I can get at the moment.

[TableLayout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz8dz.png)

As you can see, there is a gap in the header and also in the row if the row consisting 2+ lines.
I want to make the first column (which is Items) have the longest width while the other column just wraps the content with the header.

here is the XML

```
<TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="*">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size0"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            android:padding="@dimen/size5"
                            android:text="@string/items" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size0"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            android:padding="@dimen/size5"
                            android:text="@string/quantity" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size0"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            android:padding="@dimen/size5"
                            android:text="@string/unitPrice" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size0"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            android:padding="@dimen/size5"
                            android:text="@string/total" />
                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>
```

And here is the code to make dynamic row

```
private void init() {

    // Array for item
    String[] valuesItem = new String[] {
            "Room asd",
            "Room qwewq",
            "Room kadskadskl",
            "Room oeqwoeqwo",
            "Room uuawuwauaw" };

    final ArrayList<String> listItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesItem.length; ++i) {
        listItem.add(valuesItem[i]);
    }

    // Array for quantity
    String[] valuesQuantity = new String[] {
            "1",
            "1",
            "2",
            "1",
            "2" };

    final ArrayList<String> listQuantity = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesQuantity.length; ++i) {
        listQuantity.add(valuesQuantity[i]);
    }

    // Array for price
    String[] valuesPrice = new String[] {
            "10",
            "10",
            "20",
            "50",
            "30" };

    final ArrayList<String> listPrice = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesPrice.length; ++i) {
        listPrice.add(valuesPrice[i]);
    }

    // Array for total
    String[] valuesTotal = new String[] {
            "10",
            "10",
            "40",
            "50",
            "60" };

    final ArrayList<String> listTotal = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesTotal.length; ++i) {
        listTotal.add(valuesTotal[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <valuesItem.length; i++) {

        TableRow row= new TableRow(getActivity());
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        TextView item = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView quantity = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView price = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView total = new TextView(getActivity());
        item.setText(valuesItem[i]);
        quantity.setText(valuesQuantity[i]);
        price.setText(valuesPrice[i]);
        total.setText(valuesTotal[i]);
        item.setPadding(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                (getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5)),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5));
        quantity.setPadding(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5));
        price.setPadding(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5));
        total.setPadding(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5),
                getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size5));
        item.setWidth(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size0));
        quantity.setWidth(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size0));
        price.setWidth(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size0));
        total.setWidth(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size0));
        item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        quantity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        price.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        total.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        row.addView(item);
        row.addView(quantity);
        row.addView(price);
        row.addView(total);
        tableDynamic.addView(row);
    }

}
```

Sorry if it's a bit messy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by configuring LayoutParams for each TextView

```
lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5f);
        item.setLayoutParams(lp);
        lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2f);
        quantity.setLayoutParams(lp);
        lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.5f);
        price.setLayoutParams(lp);
        lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.5f);
        total.setLayoutParams(lp);
```